# Adding multiple fields in node_save()

Tags: entities, nodes

Its possible to add a node using the code below, but how do i add multiple fields?

```
$node = new StdClass();//creating a bare node
$node->type = 'answer';//giving it type
$node->status = 1;//give it a published staus
$node->title = "Step up to the FLava";//gives title
$node->body = "Body Body body"; //gives body

node_save($node);
```

Singles custom field, we can use:

```
$node->field_my_custom_field['und'][0]['value'] = 'my value';
```

But what if I want to add multiple entries for one field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second index after 'und' is used for delta of values. You can make it 1 , 2, 3 etc to add multiple values... Something like below...

```
$node->field_my_custom_field['und'][0]['value'] = 'my value one';
$node->field_my_custom_field['und'][1]['value'] = 'my value two';
$node->field_my_custom_field['und'][2]['value'] = 'my value three';
$node->field_my_custom_field['und'][3]['value'] = 'my value four';
```